# Written books from command blocks not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I enter the command:

```
/give @a minecraft:written_book 1 0 {title:a,author:a,pages:["Hello world!\n1234567890","\"Hello\"\n\\Test q"]}`
```

The books everyone get should have two pages, the first one being:

> Hello world!
>   1234567890

and the second one being:

> "Hello!"
>   \Test q

But instead both pages just say:

> Hello

What's going on and how can I fix it? I'm using MC 1.11.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use newlines in the pages (or any other formatting for that matter), the page text needs to be a json object with a text tag.

Building this require that you 'escape' some symbols:

- double quotes `"` by adding and backslash before them: `\"`
- backslash `\` by adding another backslash before it: `\\`
- replacing linebreaks with `\n`

For example if you want the literal string:

```
Hello world
embedded back\slash
"quoted" string
```

You need to turn it into this json object:

```
{ text: "Hello world\nembedded back\\slash\n\"quoted\" string" }
```

Then, to embed this in the `pages` array, you need to treat the whole json object as string and **escape it once again using the same rules**:

```
pages:["{ text: \"Hello world\\nembedded back\\\\slash\\n\\\"quoted\\\" string\" }", ...]
```

Notice how in `\"` we need to escape both the backslash and the double quote so the slash becomes `\\` and the double quote becomes `\"` and the whole `\"` becomes `\\\"`. Notice also how for the embedded backslash we need to escape each of the two backslashes `\\` individually, so they become four `\\\\`

Armed with that knowledge, your two pages:

```
Hello world!
1234567890
```

and

```
"Hello!"
\Test q
```

become as json tags:

```
{ text: "Hello world!\n1234567890" }
{ text: "\"Hello!\"\n\\Test q" }
```

and then embedding this in the `pages` array and escaping once again:

```
pages: ["{ text: \"Hello world!\\n1234567890\" }",
        "{ text: \"\\\"Hello!\\\"\\n\\\\Test q\" }"]
```

The whole command:

`/give @a minecraft:written_book 1 0 {title:a,author:a,pages: ["{ text: \"Hello world!\\n1234567890\" }", "{ text: \"\\\"Hello!\\\"\\n\\\\Test q\" }"]}`

Also, there is a little trick that can simplify handling of quotes (it still works on 1.11.2 but is destined to be removed in future versions: [source](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-83460?focusedCommentId=241836&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-241836)) - the inner json object can use single quotes for the text tag and then you don't need to escape the double quotes!

For example your second page

```
"Hello!"
\Test q
```

can be embedded in json like so:

```
{ text: '"Hello!"\n\\Test q' }
```

Notice how the double quotes are not escaped, only the backslash is. this means when putting it in the pages array we need to escape less things:

```
pages: [..., "{ text: '\"Hello!\"\\n\\\\Test q' }"]
```

But with this method, if you have single quotes inside the string it becomes worse:

```
ain't doin' nuthin'

{ text: 'ain\'t doin\' nuthin\'' }

pages: ["{ text: 'ain\\'t doin\\' nuthin\\'' }"]
```

vs

```
pages: ["{ text: \"ain't doin' nuthin'\" }"]
```

Comment: As of 1.9, lenient JSON is no longer supported. Doubles quotes must be applied to all keys and string values; single quotes will not suffice.

Comment: This is true for the command itself, i.e. you can't use single quotes in `pages: ['...']`, but you can still use single quotes in the inner string - all of the above examples are working on 1.11.2.

Comment: `pages:['...']` is NBT, not JSON, and has a completely different parser. While technically the JSON input for `pages` strings is *currently* lenient, that does not mean it's supported. It will not be that way in the future so you should not be relying on it. [Source](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-83460?focusedCommentId=241836&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-241836).

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially done by stringifying your strings:

- Open with `"\"`
- Close with `\""`
- `\"` becomes `\\\"`
- `\n` stays as `\n` (`\\\n` is a literal `\n` in the book)
- `\\` becomes `\\\\`